# Is there a way to obtain the current pattern searched in an AWK script?

Tags: regex, awk, sh, gawk

The basic idea is this. Suppose that you want to search a file for multiple patterns from a pipe with awk :

```
 ... | awk -f - '{...}' someFile.txt
```

* '...' is just short for some code
* '-f -' indicates the pattern is taken from pipe

Is there a way to know which pattern is searched at each instant within the awk script
(like you know $1 is the first field, is there something like $PATTERN that contains the current pattern
searched or a way to get something like it?
More Elaboration:
if I have 2 files:
someFile.txt containing:

```
1  
2  
4
```

patterns.txt containing:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

running this command:

```
cat patterns.txt |awk -f - '{...}' someFile.txt
```

What should I type between the braces such that only the pattern in patterns.txt that
has not been matched in someFile.txt is printed?(in this case the number 3 in patterns.txt is not matched)

Comment: To get "only the pattern in `patterns.txt` that
has not been matched in `someFile.txt`", try `grep -v someFile.txt patterns.txt`

Comment: I want to use explicitly awk here.

Comment: Are you usign the options of `awk` correctly. According to the manual page `-f` specifies the script to be executed so the following `-` just takes the script from stdin instead of taking it as the first non-option parameter (which you also supply). IHMO passing the `patterns.txt` to `awk` will result in passing each line of the `someFile.txt` to the stdout as many times as there are non-zero patterns in `patterns.txt`. This could be fixed by providing both files as normal inputs to `awk` and providing an appropriate script. Would hat help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the requirements that `patterns.txt` be supplied as stdin and that the processing be done with `awk`:

```
$ cat patterns.txt | awk 'FNR==NR{p=p "\n" $0;next;} p !~ $0' someFile.txt -
3
```

This was tested using GNU `awk`.

#### Explanation

We want to remove from patterns.txt anything that matches a line in someFile.txt. To do this, we first read in someFile.txt and create patterns from it.  Next, we print only the lines from patterns.txt that do not match any of the patterns from someFile.txt.

- `FNR==NR{p=p "\n" $0;next;}`

  `NR` is the number of lines that `awk` has read so far and `FNR` is the number of lines that `awk` has read so far from the current file.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first named file: `someFile.txt`.  We save all such lines in the newline-separated variable `p`.  We then tell `awk` to skip the remaining commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `p !~ $0`

  If we got here, then we are now reading the second named file on the command line which is `-` for stdin.  This boolean condition evaluates to either true or false.  If it is true, the line is printed.  If not, it is skipped.  In other words, the above is awk's crytic shorthand for:

  ```
  p !~ $0 {print $0}
  ```

Comment: This answer seems to work for me in output. Do you mind explaining the syntax employed here?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd | awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} {for (p in pats) if ($0 ~ p) delete pats[p]} END{ for (p in pats) print p }' - someFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way in awk

```
cat patterns.txt | awk 'NR>FNR&&!($0 in a);{a[$0]}' someFile.txt -
```